# How to Optimize this PHP Script?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a PHP script that gets executed via a Cron Job and it's taking too long (around 25 seconds each time) and I need to optimize it. While the script is running, it lags my server (doesn't let anyone access any other page until the script is finished) and I want to either cut down the amount of time it lags or optimize it where there would be next to zero lag.

I know it's hard to optimize because what the script is doing but my code is outlined below:

1. Select all users from database and fetch their token (LIMIT 0, 200)
2. Loop through all users and store that token in an array
3. For each token in the array

   1. Create an API object
   2. Make an http request to fetch new user details from API
   3. Check if an error occurred while receiving the response from the HTTP request

      1. If there is NO error then update the user with the http response which is the newest data from the API
      2. If there IS an error then set the users account to inactive

The problem with this logic is that I am sending an HTTP request and then waiting for the response and then I continue looping. What I would like to do is send ALL of the requests at once and then have a callback function that can handle the data as it gets received and do updates accordingly. However I am having trouble with it.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require('functions.php');

global $mysqli;

$select = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `token` FROM `users` ORDER BY `last_updated` ASC LIMIT 0, 200");
$select->execute();
$select->bind_result($cur_token);

$tokens = array();

while($select->fetch())
{
    array_push($tokens, $cur_token);
}

foreach($tokens as $token)
{
    $api = Instaphp\Instaphp::Instance();
    $api = Instaphp\Instaphp::Instance($token);
    $info = $api->Users->Info();

    if(empty($info->error))
    {
        $info->data->token = $token;
        $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `a` = ?, `b` = ?, `c` = ?, `d` = ?, `e` = ?, `f` = ?, `g` = ?, `h` = ?, `i` = ?, `j` = NOW() WHERE `k` = ?");
        $update->bind_param('isssssiiii', $info->data->id, $info->data->username, $info->data->bio, $info->data->website, $info->data->profile_picture, $info->data->full_name, $info->data->counts->media, $info->data->counts->followed_by, $info->data->counts->follows, $info->data->id);

        $update->execute();

    } else if($info->error->code == 400) {
        $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 0, `last_updated` = NOW() WHERE `token` = ?");
        $update->bind_param('s', $token);
        $update->execute();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: How many records are in the users table?

Comment: 5000+ and more each day @DeanRather

Comment: Have you considered lowering the process priority to minimum? On Linux, you can do this by prefacing your command with: `/bin/nice -n 20 command-name`

Comment: Instead of fetching the entire user details use a Time field in user table and if any entry got updated then update the time field .Fetch the user details only for the entries that got updated.

Comment: Do you control the API? Or is it a third party website?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for evented I/O (node.js and friends)

Comment: It'll take longer that way, but a CLI PHP script won't directly block webserver PHP calls.

Comment: though really, for a batch job like this you might just get a $7/month VPS and dedicate it to doing these updates and running backups.

Comment: @andrewsi I do not control the API. I was thinking about getting a VPS but I know there is a better way.

Comment: @sudowned How do I run a CLI PHP script from a Cron Job?

Comment: You already are. CLI means Command Line Interface. It's not directly blocking those calls, it's eating all the CPU or memory - and if it's the CPU, running it with a nice value of 20 will make the OS divide that time more equitably with other processes.

Comment: @sudowned It is blocking my site for approx 25 seconds.